# Could I have help positioning 2 texts?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position fig caption (the text that says damaged iPhone and image) in the centre below the image. And position the footer/copyright on the right side of the screen. I've tried the usual methods but it didn't seem to work, or maybe I made a small mistake that i just didn't notice Thanks for taking the time to help, have a good day!

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lindsey</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/yourCustom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head> 
<body>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" style="color:#000000">Paulo Pinzon-Iradian</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="work.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="lindsey.jpg" style="width:370px;" alt="lindsey">
            <figcaption>Damaged iPhone and Image</figcaption>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="liferockslifesucks.html" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="malek.html" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

   <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container" style="display: table; height: 50px; overflow: hidden;">
        <p class="text-muted" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">&copy; 2013-2015 Paulo Pinzon-Iradian, All Right Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:OpenSans-Regular;
    src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

.navbar-default{
    background: #fff;
    margin-top:2%;
    border:0px;
}

.navbar-brand
{
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 22px;
}

ul, li, a
{
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
}

.navbar-toggle
{
    border:0px;
}


.container .jumbotron.no-padding
{
    background: #fff;
    border:0px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    color:#000000;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    text-align: right;
}

.right.carousel-control, .left.carousel-control {
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* IE support */
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

img
{
    margin:auto;
}

figcaption
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your footer text appears to be positioned to the right? Are you talking about when the viewport changes?

Comment: its position somewhat on the right because it is right aligned. But I would like it further right

Comment: *I'm trying to position fig caption (the text that says damaged iPhone and image) in the centre below the image.* Use `display: block;` instead of `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Okay i put block instead, but sorry it still hasn't worked

Comment: Something else going on then. To shift your footer text to the right, you need to add a `width: 100%` to the container (i.e., `.footer .container { width: 100%; }`). Here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/0xr2qeft/

Comment: Yes, that worked! Okay I see, thanks very much :) I still just need help positioning the fig caption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you: your `figcaption` is set to left so just change it to center and your footer CSS can be `.footer .container` to adjust to position.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
  src: url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: 0px;
}
.navbar.navbar-brand {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 22px;
}
ul,
li,
a {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  border: 0px;
}
.container .jumbotron.no-padding {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  color: #000000;
}
.footer .container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
.right.carousel-control,
.left.carousel-control {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* IE support */
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  margin: auto;
}
figcaption {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" style="color:#000000">Paulo Pinzon-Iradian</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="work.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Work</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/f00" style="width:370px;" alt="lindsey">
      <figcaption>Damaged iPhone and Image</figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="liferockslifesucks.html" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="malek.html" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container" style="display: table; height: 50px; overflow: hidden;">
    <p class="text-muted" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">&copy; 2013-2015 Paulo Pinzon-Iradian, All Right Reserved</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Yes this worked! thanks very much for helping me :) !